Definition of Barycentric subdivision in Dold


This is the definition from Dold's Lectures on Algebraic Topology (page 40). I am not sure I understand the meaning of $\beta _q\iota _q$, how is this even well defined? Since $\iota$ is a map from a simplex to a simplex, it is not an element of $S_q X$ so this interpretation also doesn't work. Hope someone can point out my misunderstanding. Thanks!

What is the definition of $S_qX$?

@FShrike SX is the Singular Complex (elements of $S_qX$ are singular simplices)

The map $\iota_q$ is an element of $S_q\Delta_q$, so $\beta_q\iota_q\in S_q\Delta_q$. This is defined inductively (over $q$) via the first two equations of (6.2). Now, if $X$ is any space and $\sigma_q\in S_qX$, we define $\beta_q(\sigma_q)$ via the third equation of (6.2), i.e. as $\sigma_q(\beta_q\iota_q)$. Here, $\sigma_q\colon\Delta_q\rightarrow X$ as a map is not notationally distinguished from its induced homomorphism $\sigma_q\colon S_q\Delta_q\rightarrow S_qX$, which maps $\beta_q\iota_q\in S_q\Delta_q$ to $\beta_q(\sigma_q)\in S_qX$.
The intuition is as follows: Any singular simplex of a space is the pushforward of some identity simplex, so if we want the definition of $\beta_q$ to be natural, the third equation of (6.2) is forced upon us and it remains to define how to barycentrically subdivide the simplex itself, which is done inductively (and you can draw explicit pictures for this process).
